# How to update Fedora Xfce to the latest version (37)

Tags: fedora, upgrade, version, dnf

I've got a Fedora Xfce version 35 install that has been barking at me about being past the date for support.  So I installed all the updates that were available, but I still see that I'm on version 35 when I peek at `/etc/os-release`.

Using `dnf upgrade` does not seem to change this.

How do I upgrade to the latest -- version 37??

Comment: I did not, because I didn't know where to look.  I'm kinda new to modern Fedora (used it last over a decade ago).  I had it just for one app: six(1), but now I think I'm moving the other 6 hosts in my cluster over to Fedora (from Xubuntu).  Make this comment an answer and if it succeeds, I'll accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The upgrade instructions with a few different ways to do it are clearly spelled out on the Fedora Documentation website.

https://docs.fedoraproject.org/en-US/quick-docs/upgrading/